# Analyticity of the generalized susceptibility in the linear response theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, linear-systems, analyticity

In linear response theory, the generalized susceptibility $\chi(\omega)$ is defined as $$\chi(\omega)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\phi(t) e^{i\omega t} dt, ~~t\geq 0\tag{1}$$ where $\phi(t)$ is the response function$^1$. If it is assumed that $\chi(\omega)$ exists for all real, non-negative $\omega$, then its integral representation as given in (1) suggests that $\chi(\omega)$ also exists when ${\rm Im}\omega\geq 0$ i.e., in the complex upper half plane of $\omega$. This is because an additional damping factor increases the convergence of the integral (1). From (1), how can one argue that $\chi(\omega)$ is also analytic in the complex upper half plane of $\omega$? It's crucial in deriving the so-called Kramer's-Kronig relations in physics.

---

$^1$ On physical grounds, $\phi(t)$ is smooth (which @AFT enquired in his comment) and is also bounded as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: What is $\phi(t)$? What are its analytic properties? Is it smooth?

Comment: In addition to providing sufficient information about $\phi$ to answer the question, could you also explain how this is a better fit for physics than for [math.SE]?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, this is a mathematical question, but it arises most naturally in the study of dispersion/absorption theory and response functions. So it would be useful to have good answers here on physics.se.

Comment: Doesn't the analyticity property follow from *causality*, I.e. The fact that $\phi(t)$ is the response function of a physical system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that this follows from *causality*, namely that $\phi(t)=0$ for $t<0$. Physically, the response of the system cannot precede the perturbation that causes it.

In your integral defining $\chi(\omega)$, the lower limit of integration may therefore be extended to $-\infty$, making $\phi(t)$ and $\chi(\omega)$ a Fourier transform pair. Then the [Titchmarsh theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TitchmarshTheorem.html) applies: $\chi(\omega)$ is analytic in the upper half complex plane of $\omega$.

Comment: I think this is correct. A useful discussion is in D. Forster, "Hydrodynamic Fluctuations, Broken Symmetry, And Correlation Functions". It is a very good book.